# javascript parameter with database content

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I want to hide and show of the content for each category

```
{% for category in categorys %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button onclick="myFunction('{{category.content|escape}}')">{{category.title}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So i'm trying to get what i have in parameter in my javascript.
But i have nothink in my alert

```
function myFunction(content) {
  alert(content);
  console.log(content);
}
</script>
```

So in my consol log i find this

```
5:219 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: Look at the HTML your template is generating. See if you can spot an errors with it. Look in the developer tools in your browser. See if it highlights any errors.

Comment: It's been awhile, since i did any inline onclick handler, but you may have to put quotation marks, ie `<button onclick="myFunction('{{category.content}}')">{{category.title}}</button>`

Comment: In my consol log i have this : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list i also update the quotation marks

Comment: You need to [escape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/escape.html) the variable for `JS` otherwise it could break the syntax!

Comment: I add a change i do this  `category.content|escape` i don't if u mean to do that

Comment: U have to do `|escape('js')` as the default escape method is `html` in twig

Comment: That work thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like that say in comment i needed to add escape to the parameter of my OnClick like that  -> `{{category.content|escape('js')}}`